# Inject date using @Value annotation

Tags: spring, date, annotations, code-injection

This is how I am trying to inject a date into a @Component class.

```
@Value("${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyyMMdd\").parse(\"${PROP_DATE}\")}")
Date myDate;
```

The date is specified as a String in properties file :

```
PROP_DATE=20110421
```

I get this error. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to inject Date property? Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ccc': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.util.Date aaa.bbb.ccc.myDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20110421")'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyyMMdd\").parse(\"${PROP_DATE}\")}` for process value with spEL