# Can I use @Value to parse and inject a Calendar item in Spring 3.2 for Java?

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations, spring-el

I have an application that uses springs `@PropertySource` to create a bean parsed from my property-file.

Later I try to inject some of those values into a field using `@Value`.

property-file:

```
# StartDate in format yyyy-MM-dd
startDate=2013-12-05
# EndDate in format yyyy-MM-dd
endDate=2013-12-06
```

BeanConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:wfmConfig.properties")
public class WfmConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Injection:

```
@Value("#(Calendar.getInstance().setTime(new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-    dd\").parse(\"$endDate}\"))}")
private Calendar endDate;
```

This spEL-parsing works wonderful for Date-objects as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066482/inject-date-using-value-annotation).

Why doesnt this work? Is there any way to utilize Calendar here instead of Date?

Comment: The result of `setTime` is `void`  not a `Calendar`. When using the `@Value` annotation the normal spring converters are still active. You could create a `StringToCalendarConverter` to do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks. that was an obvious blunder, but i have no luck defining a method to do this.

It just screams at me that this new method cannot be located.

I worked arround it by using Date instead wich has a native injector.